# Payload size of a gzip archive

Tags: gzip

Is there any way to check the normal size of the compressed datasets (`.gz`) without decompressing it?

For example, I have 50 large `.gz` files (in total 50 Gb) that can't be decompressed due to storage issue but I want to report how much normal data is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-l` option. From the manpage:

> ```
>    -l --list
>          For each compressed file, list the following fields:
>
>              compressed size: size of the compressed file
>              uncompressed size: size of the uncompressed file
>              ratio: compression ratio (0.0% if unknown)
>              uncompressed_name: name of the uncompressed file
> ```

Even if that option wouldn't be available, you still wouldn't need any storage space to uncompress the files and measure their size:

```
gzip -cd file.gz | wc -c
```

Comment: There's a caveat with `-l`: it only works for files up to 4GB (uncompressed). See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183465 for details.