# Tar extract size

Tags: tar, size

Is it possible to find out, what will be size of a directory after extract ?

If I do have a `tar` file in `gz,bz2 or xz` format of 1GB then is there any way to know beforehand that this `tar` file will need so much size for extracting the content ?

Answer (score 1):

An uncompressed tarball is approximately the same size as its extracted contents, so you can get a very good idea of the extracted size by determining the size of the original tarball (pre-compression):

```
xz -l tarball.tar.xz
gzip -tl tarball.tar.gz
```

respectively for `xz` and `gzip` (although [`gzipped` files larger than 4GB won't report the correct size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183465/86440)).

`bzip2` doesn't appear to have an option to show the size of the file before compression, so the easiest option is to decompress and count:

```
bunzip2 -c tarball.tar.bz2 | wc -c
```

which also works for large `gzip` files:

```
gunzip -c tarball.tar.gz | wc -c
```

Answer (score 0):

check here...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712173/check-the-total-content-size-of-a-tar-gz-file

```
$ tar tzvf archive.tar.gz | sed 's/ \+/ /g' | cut -f3 -d' ' | sed '2,$s/^/+ /' | paste -sd' ' | bc
```

---

```
gzsize <your file>
```