# gzip uncompressing a bigger file than it lists

Tags: raspberry-pi, elementary-os, gzip, 7z

So when I use the list flag of `gzip` the uncompressed size is listed as 3.5g (with ratio of -9.0%):

```
$ gzip -l piTorrentbox101216.gz
    compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
     3843992911          3527409664  -9.0% piTorrentbox101216
```

But when I decompress the file I get an even bigger filesize than listed in the last command:

```
$ ls -l 
   7822376960 jan 26 13:02 piTorrentbox101216
```

I also tried decompressing using `7zip` but it gives me this output:

```
$ 7z x piTorrentbox101216.gz

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: piTorrentbox101216.gz

Extracting  piTorrentbox101216
ERROR: E_FAIL
```

I want to burn this backed up image to my raspberrypi brand new SD card (which is 7.7g). I have already burned this image to an old card that was also 7.7g and it worked fine every time but now that the old SD is broken I had to buy a new one.

So, why is it that `gzip` unzips more than it should? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`gzip` isn't extracting more than it should, you've just hit the 32-bit limit on the size field, so `gzip -l` can't give the correct result, but the extraction can.

You may find [Fastest way of working out uncompressed size of large GZIPPED file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183465/fastest-way-of-working-out-uncompressed-size-of-large-gzipped-file) relevant!

Comment: But i'm still confused because I have burned that same image into a 7.7gb SD card (exactly the same size as this one and both are kingston). I don't understand what is wrong with this one.

Comment: The extracted image is 7.2GiB in size, so there shouldn't be any problem writing it to your SD card.