# Compression Utility Max Files Size Limit | Unix/Linux

Tags: compression, gzip

In Unix/Linux is there any max files size limit that a compression utility ( gzip/compress) can compress. I remember years ago it was mentioned in the gzip page that it can compress files up to 4 gb. Actually I need to compress fillies of around 512 GB regularly. I tested few files with compress utility and found hash code(MD5) of the DB files before compress and after un-compress are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gzip` nowadays can compress files larger than 4 GiB in size, and in fact doesn’t have any limit of its own really (you’ll be limited by the underlying file system). The only limitation with files larger than 4 GiB is that `gzip -l`, in version 1.11 or older, won’t report their size correctly; see [Fastest way of working out uncompressed size of large GZIPPED file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183465/86440) for an alternative. This has been fixed in `gzip` 1.12; [`gzip -l`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gzip.git/commit/?id=32fef43b442c7abc70414863d64718cd06f6477a) decompresses the data to determine the real size of the original data, instead of showing the stored size.

There are many other compression tools which provide better compression and/or speed, which you might find more appropriate: [XZ](https://tukaani.org/xz/), [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)...

Answer (score 1):

Gzip is concatenatable stream comptression  (see "advanced usage" in the man page) so if the algorithm hits a hard encoding limit (*) it can just end the current stream and start a new stream.

So there is no hard limit on data size in the gzip itself

(* I don't know enough about `Xflate` to say if there is a limit or not)