# Uncompressed file estimation wrong?

Tags: compression, gzip, split

I had a large (~60G) compressed file (`tar.gz`).

I used `split` to break it into 4 parts and then `cat` to join them back together.

However, now, when I am trying to estimate the size of the uncompressed file, it turns out it is smaller than the original? How is this possible?

```
$ gzip -l myfile.tar.gz 
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
        60680003101          3985780736 -1422.4% myfile.tar
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is caused by the size of the field used to store the uncompressed size in gzipped files: it’s only 32 bits, so `gzip` can only store sizes of files up to 4 GiB. Anything larger is compressed and uncompressed correctly, but `gzip -l` gives an incorrect uncompressed size in versions 1.11 and older.

So splitting the tarball and reconstructing it hasn’t caused this, and shouldn’t have affected the file — if you want to make sure, you can check it with `gzip -tv`.

See [Fastest way of working out uncompressed size of large GZIPPED file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183465/86440) for more details, and [the `gzip` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/html_node/Invoking-gzip.html#Invoking-gzip):

> The `gzip` format represents the input size modulo *2³²*, so the uncompressed size and compression ratio are listed incorrectly for uncompressed files 4 GiB and larger.